# how to merge all routing paths in one Route attribute in asp.net core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, swagger

I am working on net core 5 project and I am trying to create an API's wit dynamic URL path's
so I started with using `Route` Attribute like the following

```
[Route("customPath")]
[Rout("anotherCustomPath")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
   return new string[] { "value1", "value2"};
}
```

My question is how can I mix the two `Route` attributes in one attribute to be something like

```
[Route("customPath,anotherCustomPath")]
```

and to get custom paths values from a dynamic `string` ?